# AttributeError: 'DType' object has no attribute 'type'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

When I receive the training produces loss and accuracy (they are both tensor), I would like to use tf.comPat.v1.Keras.Utils.Progbar()function and the update method to update them, so that I can get a better look training process, but the following error occured:

```
 File "E:/python/maml_mnist/train.py", line 64, in <module>
,('accuracy',mean_train_meta_acc)]
File "C:\Users\12130\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 442, in update
avg = np.mean(self._values[k][0] / max(1, self._values[k][1]))
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in mean
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3373, in mean
out=out, **kwargs)
File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 170, in _mean
ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)
AttributeError: 'DType' object has no attribute 'type' here
```

The code is as follows:

```
train_progbar = tf.compat.v1.keras.utils.Progbar(train_data.steps)
for i in range(train_data.steps):
    batch_train_loss,batch_train_acc = maml.train_on_batch(train_data.get_one_batch(),
                                                               inner_optimizer,
                                                               inner_step=1,
                                                               outer_optimizer=outer_optimizer)

    train_meta_loss.append(batch_train_loss)
    train_meta_acc.append(batch_train_acc)
    mean_train_meta_loss = np.mean(train_meta_loss)
    mean_train_meta_acc = np.mean(batch_train_acc)

    train_progbar.update(i+1
                             ,[('loss',mean_train_meta_loss)
                            ,('accuracy',mean_train_meta_acc)]
                             )
```

I know that the error was caused by  solving the average, but I don't know how to fix it to make the code run successfully.

My version of TensorFlow is 1.14.0.

Comment: What are the types of `batch_train_loss` and `batch_train_acc`? And are `train_meta_loss` and `train_meta_acc` initialized as empty lists? I can not reproduce your problem on Google Colab.

Comment: And what is your numpy version? It looks very strange, the trackback is indicating that perhaps you apply `np.mean` to a tensor when call `train_progbar.update()`, however, you call `np.mean(train_meta_loss)` successfully.

Comment: Sorry to see your comment so late, my problem really is that train_meta_loss and train_meta_acc were not initialized as empty list. Thank you very much for your advice.